# The monitored command dumped core?

Tags: c

Well on a regular basis i get obstructed with this error , the monitored command dumped core.

Which is pretty much alien language to me, hence i cannot not possibly understand what the compiler is saying.

I looked up the internet , for what could be the reason and found out that i could be accessing index which has not been allocated memory, therefore i set on to make a simplest code possible and encounter the same error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    int a[100000];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int j=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i+2)
    {   

        if (i%2==0)
            {   
                 a[j]=i;
                 j+=1;
            }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

But i don't understand how i could be accessing non allocated memory.

Also what could be the other reasons for the same error to occur such frequently.

Comment: Is the incrementation in the for loop only run once?, i don't think so.

Comment: Although you can allocate 100k integers on the stack of most modern desktop or server class machines, you can't necessarily allocate much more.  On most Windows systems, you probably couldn't allocate 300k integers (1 MiB stack); on most Unix systems, you probably couldn't allocate 2 million integers on the stack (8 MiB stack).  So, be cautious.  At the moment, you're OK, but it wouldn't be hard to run into problems.

Comment: i+2 did you mean i=i+2 ?

Comment: As for "the monitored program dumped core" message, that means that the development environment you're using ran your program, but your program crashed.  That, in turn, means that your program has a bug.  You need to get out the debugger and run the program in the debugger to find out why it is crashing.  Or you need to add print statements to your code to tell you what it's doing before it goes wrong.  Don't forget to recompile after editing your code.

Comment: Could anyone also explain other reasons for the same error , because i encounter it too frequently.

Comment: The most common reasons are 'memory abuse' — accessing invalid memory, either because the base pointer is invalid (e.g. NULL, but that's the easy case; there are lots of other invalid but not NULL pointers), or because the offset from the base pointer is invalid (too large most often; occasionally too small, meaning negative).  There are other possibilities, but not that many.  Check your system calls for error returns — especially if things start going wrong.  Learn to use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if it works on your platform; it works wonders diagnosing the hard to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue could be your `for` loop, as in the third part you're not updating `i`. To update, write it as `i=i+2` or `i+=2`.

Comment: Is the incrementation in the for loop only run once?, i don't think so.

Comment: @KshitijDhyani: you have `i+2` rather than `i = i + 2` or `i += 2` in the loop 'increment', so you don't change `i` in your current loop, so it just keeps on going, with `j` incrementing and going out of control (overwriting out of bounds of the array).  You could print `i` and `j` inside the loop (`printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);` and watch how `i` stays at `0` and `j` keeps on increasing until your program crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Your index `j`  gets out of bounds:

Demonstration:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n;
  int a[100000];
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int j = 0;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i + 2)
  {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
      if (j > 100000)      // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      {
        printf("Bummer\n");
        return 1;
      }
      a[j] = i;
      j += 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Accessing an array with out of bounds results undefined behaviour (google that term).

Comment: Yes, i understand what u could be saying, but that would be when i put in values greater than 100000,which is not happening , its saying the error even before compiling, help is appreciated , thanks.

Comment: Yes you are, run the program I provided in my  answer. The program prints "Bummer" and stops as soon as `j` is larger than 10000

Comment: Yes, i understand that j is getting bigger, but could you explain how, i feel that if n<100000 then j would never be satisfy your condition because i am only incrementing it inside the for loop and for loop it self is running only 100000 times. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing the value of i. You have written i+2 instead of i+=2.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    int a[100000];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int j=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i+=2)
    {   

        if (i%2==0)
            {   
                 a[j]=i;
                 j+=1;
            }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing i+2 ,but you have to write i+=2.